# Store the data collected in the interrupt handler esp8266

Tags: c, sdk, esp8266

The main idea is to receive the TLS key, SSID and password to esp8266 by light.
I implemented some simple protocol with a clock signal and data signal.
I can read the data and write it to serial to see what is going on. 
But the main problem is that data can be the different length and my C lang knowledge is not enough to provide the storing this data in the variable. The data will be the JSON string.

---

```
LOCAL void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR beam_intr_handler(void)
{
  if (GPIO_REG_READ(GPIO_STATUS_ADDRESS) & BIT(BUTTON_PIN))
  {
    //disable interrupt
    gpio_pin_intr_state_set(GPIO_ID_PIN(BUTTON_PIN), GPIO_PIN_INTR_DISABLE);

    //clear interrupt status
    GPIO_REG_WRITE(GPIO_STATUS_W1TC_ADDRESS, GPIO_REG_READ(GPIO_STATUS_ADDRESS) & BIT(BUTTON_PIN));

    os_printf("tick %d \r\n", system_get_time());
    os_printf("sensor states %d\r\n", ((GPIO_REG_READ(GPIO_IN_ADDRESS) & (BIT(SENSOR_PIN1))) != 0));
  }
}
```